# How to get customized key values from Firebase?

Tags: android

I want to retrieve the value of Component_ from the above picture.
I have tried to retrieve the values but i can't. There is no help i found in internet .
Anybody can help me out i will be very thankful to you.
Thank you.

[How to get the value using firebase java.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dwRF.png)